# off-the-shelf HDD in Dell Optiplex 755 - Invalid Replacement - Press F1 when rebooting

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-optiplex

I recently put an SSD into my work Optiplex 755. Since then, every time the system boots or reboots, I get prompted to hit F1 to continue with a message like

> HDD replacement is not valid

The system works just fine. What I am gathering from Dell's website is that I left the original drive internally as a data drive. And apparently the Optiplex does not support 2 drives in the configuration we purchased originally and complains.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this message? some suggested the MEBx or whatever from Intel and to turn it off, but I did not succeed earlier.

It's not a big deal 80% of the time, but I regularly work from home and occasionally need to fire a reboot and well, you don't get the BIOS screen remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
Figured out how to *trick* the BIOS. Use the eSATA connector of the motherboard. I should have mentioned that we have a SFF chassis. So, I ended up with the following:

- SSD on SATA0
- Optical Drive on SATA1
- Original HDD on eSATA

This way, the BIOS does not complain and let's you have the SSD *and* the original HDD.

*Please note that my system was already configured in RAID/AHCI/AutoDetect. According to DELL, certain configuration will require the RAID/AHCI to be enabled for the eSATA to work. If you must change this setting, you are running the risk of unstability in Windows XP*

Answer (score 3):

I received the "HDD Replacement Not Valid" error on my Dell Optiplex 755 after I installed a second hard drive. The solution is simple - In the BIOS, go to "Post Behaviour" and then "Keyboard Errors" and change the setting to "Do Not Report." The factory default is "Do Not Report." My first impression after making the change was that it wouldn't work cos I didn't think the error fell under the category "Keyboard Error," but it worked!

Comment: Perfect. It still seems to report it (contrary to what the setting says), but it doesn't halt, and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Dell 755 Desktop is configured to reject anything but a Western Digital or Samsung hard drive, claiming it is due to "thermal considerations". Other companies make low-power green hard drives and SSD that do not run hot.

['HDD replacement is not valid' Message on Dell Optiplex Computer - KB Article - 329305 | Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_37EC4B1BCD6C9532E040A68F5B28094C&isLegacy=true)

Some report DELL ships the 755 with Seagate from the factory and it also causes this message.

[Mystery warning while installing 2d HDD (320 gb Se... - Seagate Community Forums](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-Barracuda/Mystery-warning-while-installing-2d-HDD-320-gb-Seagate-Barracuda/m-p/2545)

If your brand drive runs too hot, it would be careless to simply turn off the warnings and ignore the problem. This should not be an issue with an SSD but this old DELL technology doesn't compute that factor.